# tcp fact retransmission delays successive datapakage, and update window size

Tags: tcp, tcpdump

i'm testing tcp related functionality. client connects to server and send data every 66ms, with tcp_nodelay set.

when a package is lost, i'm expecting that 3 duplicate ack is received and fast retransmission is started, the lost package is retransmited and generated new data is transmitted with no delay(every 66ms).

but the tcpdump shows me that, first the window size becomes larger, and successive new package is only transmited when a new ack arrived.

```
10:18:16.622232 IP 184.*.*.*.42766 > 193.*.*.*.2099: Flags [P.], seq 6325:6387, ack 1, win 457, options [nop,nop,TS val 23063446 ecr 205448249], length 62
10:18:16.643665 IP 193.*.*.*.2099 > 184.*.*.*.42766: Flags [.], ack 6263, win 310, options [nop,nop,TS val 205448265 ecr 23063413], length 0
10:18:16.710056 IP 193.*.*.*.2099 > 184.*.*.*.42766: Flags [.], ack 6325, win 310, options [nop,nop,TS val 205448282 ecr 23063429], length 0
10:18:16.753846 IP 184.*.*.*.42766 > 193.*.*.*.2099: Flags [P.], seq 6449:6511, ack 1, win 457, options [nop,nop,TS val 23063479 ecr 205448282], length 62
10:18:16.776349 IP 193.*.*.*.2099 > 184.*.*.*.42766: Flags [.], ack 6387, win 310, options [nop,nop,TS val 205448298 ecr 23063446], length 0
10:18:16.820181 IP 184.*.*.*.42766 > 193.*.*.*.2099: Flags [P.], seq 6511:6573, ack 1, win 457, options [nop,nop,TS val 23063495 ecr 205448298], length 62
10:18:16.885504 IP 184.*.*.*.42766 > 193.*.*.*.2099: Flags [P.], seq 6573:6635, ack 1, win 457, options [nop,nop,TS val 23063512 ecr 205448298], length 62
10:18:16.907999 IP 193.*.*.*.2099 > 184.*.*.*.42766: Flags [.], ack 6387, win 319, options [nop,nop,TS val 205448331 ecr 23063446,nop,nop,sack 1 {6449:6511}], length 0
10:18:16.951821 IP 184.*.*.*.42766 > 193.*.*.*.2099: Flags [P.], seq 6635:6697, ack 1, win 457, options [nop,nop,TS val 23063528 ecr 205448331], length 62
10:18:16.974209 IP 193.*.*.*.2099 > 184.*.*.*.42766: Flags [.], ack 6387, win 327, options [nop,nop,TS val 205448348 ecr 23063446,nop,nop,sack 1 {6449:6573}], length 0
10:18:17.018129 IP 184.*.*.*.42766 > 193.*.*.*.2099: Flags [P.], seq 6697:6759, ack 1, win 457, options [nop,nop,TS val 23063545 ecr 205448348], length 62
10:18:17.039598 IP 193.*.*.*.2099 > 184.*.*.*.42766: Flags [.], ack 6387, win 336, options [nop,nop,TS val 205448364 ecr 23063446,nop,nop,sack 1 {6449:6635}], length 0
10:18:17.039633 IP 184.*.*.*.42766 > 193.*.*.*.2099: Flags [P.], seq 6387:6449, ack 1, win 457, options [nop,nop,TS val 23063550 ecr 205448364], length 62
10:18:17.105851 IP 193.*.*.*.2099 > 184.*.*.*.42766: Flags [.], ack 6387, win 344, options [nop,nop,TS val 205448381 ecr 23063446,nop,nop,sack 1 {6449:6697}], length 0
10:18:17.105888 IP 184.*.*.*.42766 > 193.*.*.*.2099: Flags [P.], seq 6759:6821, ack 1, win 457, options [nop,nop,TS val 23063567 ecr 205448381], length 62
10:18:17.172216 IP 193.*.*.*.2099 > 184.*.*.*.42766: Flags [.], ack 6387, win 352, options [nop,nop,TS val 205448397 ecr 23063446,nop,nop,sack 1 {6449:6759}], length 0
10:18:17.172251 IP 184.*.*.*.42766 > 193.*.*.*.2099: Flags [P.], seq 6821:6883, ack 1, win 457, options [nop,nop,TS val 23063583 ecr 205448397], length 62
10:18:17.193679 IP 193.*.*.*.2099 > 184.*.*.*.42766: Flags [.], ack 6759, win 352, options [nop,nop,TS val 205448403 ecr 23063550], length 0
```

1. we can see that 6387-6449 package was lost, and the duplicate ack increase win from 310-319-327-336-344-352.
2. 6697:6759  data was sent at 17.018129, 6759:6821 was sent at 17.105888, which is delayed, not the original gap of 66ms.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Generally speaking, you will have a much better chance of getting help if you post a capture file somewhere rather than a screen shot.